# gdb - finding the values of strncmp() function

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I have a code which has hit a seg fault with strncmp() and I have this info below:

```
#7  0x00007f3662e5d4e7 in __strncmp_sse42 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) info locals
No symbol table info available.
(gdb) info args
No symbol table info available.
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 7, frame at 0x7f35f4413b70:
 rip = 0x7f3662e5d4e7 in __strncmp_sse42; saved rip = 0x7f35f64f5d6d
 called by frame at 0x7f35f4413cc0, caller of frame at 0x7f35f4413b68
 Arglist at 0x7f35f4413b60, args:
 Locals at 0x7f35f4413b60, Previous frame's sp is 0x7f35f4413b70
 Saved registers:
  rip at 0x7f35f4413b68
```

Is there a way to check the args passed into this function? Any explanation will help me relate what is going on.

Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried GDB's `backtrace` command to show the args on the caller's side?

Comment: Are you compiling with debug information being emitted (`-g` for gcc and clang)?

Comment: I am using `-Wall -Werror -g -fPIC` in the compilation @Shawn

Comment: Using the address location (at least), can I trace back to the strings?

Answer (score 1):

One way to trace args passed into system calls is to use `ltrace`.  Not always guaranteed to be helpful, but quick and painless to try.  Here's example of using ltrace to trace the calls made by particular invocation of `grep` command:

```
$ ltrace -s 200   grep XYZ hello.cc  2>&1 | grep XYZ
memcpy(0xe7f030, "XYZ\0", 4)                     = 0xe7f030
memchr("XYZ", '\n', 3)                           = nil
memcpy(0xe7f6b0, "XYZ", 3)                       = 0xe7f6b0
strlen("XYZ")                                    = 3
strncmp("Y", "XYZ", 3)                           = 1
strncmp("XYZ", "Y", 1)                           = -1
strlen("XYZ")                                    = 3
strcmp("XYZ", "XYZ")                             = 0
strlen("XYZ")                                    = 3
memcpy(0xe7f630, "XYZ\0", 4)                     = 0xe7f630
strlen("XYZ")                                    = 3
memcpy(0xe7f840, "XYZ", 3)                       = 0xe7f840
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying which operating system you're using, but try installing debug symbols for libc. E.g. libc6-dbg on Ubuntu/Debian.

Comment: I am using SLES 64bit linux

Comment: Try installing the glibc-debuginfo package.